# Oracle - Refresh complex materialized view in trigger?

Tags: oracle, updates, ddl, materialized-views, database-trigger

I'm trying to accomplish materialized view refresh after updates on any of source tables. Materialized view DDL looks like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW EMPLOYEES_GROUPS_FLAT
CACHE AS
SELECT UNIQUE end_groups AS group_id,employee_id
FROM (
  SELECT group_id AS end_group,CONNECT_BY_ROOT group_id AS root_group
  FROM privilege_groups
  START WITH group_id IN (SELECT group_id FROM employees_groups)
  CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_group_id=group_id
)
RIGHT JOIN employees_groups ON (root_group=group_id)
```

I tried to use `ON COMMIT` rebuild but it seems it doesn't support nested select. In general this query looks quite complex for fast update on commit. I also tried triggers but they don't seem to include recently added value. I don't have database permissions to use job scheduling. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Rebuild or Refresh?. Because the title says refresh ,and you also say "I'm trying to accomplish materialized view rebuild "

Comment: i get ORA-00976 because of START WITH `PRIOR`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Am surprised to see why you didn't get other issue prior to what you posted. I mean if you execute the above query it should had already been thrown error at `GROM privilege_groups`. Here `from` is mis-spelt as `GROM`.

Comment: @XING no, i already saw it and by ignoring i've tried the sql :)

Comment: Have you tried `ON DEMAND` instead of `ON COMMIT`

Comment: Sorry it was rewritten, not copypasted so typos could happen. Wait... actually it's completely messed up, I missed whole `CONNECT BY` clause... @BarbarosÖzhan `ON DEMAND` requires manual reload right? I'm rather looking for some automatic mechanism.